# What is Fabricjs alternative for context.drawImage full syntax?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to use fabricjs to render images and do some processing.
I can use this when it comes to normal rendering onto canvas , but I am failing in case of FabricJS:
This is canvas code without fabricjs :

Clip the image and position the clipped part on the canvas:
JavaScript syntax:  `context.drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height);`

How to achieve the same using FabricJS?

```
    hiddenContext.putImageData(imageDataArr, 0, 0);
    var hc = document.getElementById(hid);
    //assigning last working canvas.
    LWC = CWC;
    CWC = fabricFH;
    CWC.backgroundColor = "white";
    CWC.add(new fabric.Image(hc, 
    {
        alignX : "mid",
        alignY : "mid",
        selectable : false, 
        hasBorders : false,
        hasControls : false, 
        hasRotatingPoint : false,
        lockUniScaling: true,
        centeredScaling: true,
        scaleX: $("#"+activeCanvas).find("canvas").get(0).width/hc.width,
        scaleY: $("#"+activeCanvas).find("canvas").get(0).height/hc.height,
    }
    ));
```

Above code lets me maintain aspect ratio and render perfectly onto the canvas, but I am loosing quality of the image, because my canvas is 1000*800 and image is 2130*1800.

Can you help me in rendering the image with exact quality as per the actual image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://i2.ooshirts.com/images/lab_shirts/Cobalt-1-F.jpg';
var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
            left: 10,
            top: 10,
            angle: 0,
            width:300,
            height:240,
            clipTo: function(ctx){
                ctx.rect(-100,-100,200,200);              
               }
        });
canvas.add(imgInstance);
canvas.renderAll();
```

If we wanna **map it** with:

```
context.drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height); where

img=Specifies the image , 
sx= Optional. The x coordinate where to start  clipping,
sy= Optional. The y coordinate where to start  clipping,
swidth= Optional. The width of the clipped image,   
sheight= ptional. The height of the clipped image,  
x= The x coordinate where to place the image on the canvas, 
y= The y coordinate where to place the image on the canvas, 
width= Optional. The width of the image to use,
height= Optional. The height of the image to use     then

   fabric img <=> img
   clipTo->ctx.rect <=> sx,sy,swidth,sheight,
   left <=> x,
   top <=> y,
   width <=> width ,
   height <=> height
```

**Hope this is clear now :)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you relate the arguments as per the question?

Comment: Your answer seems promising . Can you add a jsFiddle where I can adjust a higher resolution image onto a smaller canvas. Let us say 1500*1000 image onto 500*500 canvas.

Comment: I have updated my code that takes care of aspect ratio, but I am unable to render the image with same quality. Can you do this?